# json_encode($_POST) gets stored as null in database

Tags: php, mysql, json, post

I have a script that receives hooks sent by wufoo.com when a new survey is entered on our survey links. The first thing I do in my code is to store the post value like this...

```
$post = $_POST;
$db->insert('hook_log', [ 'log_text' => json_encode($post) ]);
```

$db is a class file that has an insert function that transforms input array into insert statements and executes them in the table/database.

The above works for the most parts, but occasionally, I get a null inserted into the hook_log table. The more perplexing part though is that the subsequent part of the code has successfully received proper data and has created the required rows in the database.

In fact before the $db->insert(), I have the following code, the inside of which is never triggered.

```
$post = $_POST;

if ($post == null) {
    $db->insert('hook_log', [ 'log_text' => "Post was empty!! Checking for input: ".json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input')) ]);
    $db->insert('hook_log', [ 'log_text' => "May be get: ".json_encode($_GET) ]);
    $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

Hence, apparently my script is receiving proper POST data, but somehow cannot json_encode it and store it properly in the table. My column is latin1 encoded, and if it receives an unicode character, I see that it gets escaped properly in a test.

I even tried logging getallheaders() and it shows that some data has been posted. Can someone suggest what I should do to figure out why my code is storing NULLs and how to prevent this?

EDIT:

I am not sure whether it matters, but I don't directly input clear text into the table, the code stores encrypted data using aes_encrypt(). However, as mentioned earlier, the code works for the most part and shows proper output when I use aes_decrypt().

Comment: Instead of `if ($post == null) {`, how about checking `if(is_array($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {` as `$_POST` will always be an array and it should be a non-empty array, in this case.

Comment: Ok, I have added that to the list of conditions. Let's wait for the next hook. I have also added a line to dump the $_POST without encryption and have also made it insert json_last_error(). Will update soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simpler than what I thought. Apparently 5,000 characters was not enough to store the incoming POST data. If I didn't encrypt it before inserting, I'd have noticed the string getting truncated. Since it was truncated, even aes_decrypt didn't work properly and was returning null.

I have now increased column size to 65,000 and will observe if any more nulls are getting returned. Ideally, MySQL should have warned me about string truncation on insert.